# Unable to Understand Message GCM

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm dealing with Eclipse Luna to build the web app (jsp,java) while dealing with Eclipse Juno to build the android app. Plus, i'm referring to this link as my tutorial http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

Registration id generated successfully in android device.
This what appears when the message is push respectively in the GCM

[ messageId=0:1407227521756362%31e4cc17f9fd7ecd ]

What does it mean? How to fix it since i should have a message received at the Emulator and im not getting it.....?

Thank you.

Comment: The response you got means GCM server accepted your message. Therefore the problem must be in your app. Please include your code. And make sure your network doesn'k block ports 5228-5230.

Comment: @Eran Means i have to allow port 5228 and 5230 first right?

Comment: Plus, i just apply and run the code that given in the tutorial (Java) http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

Comment: If your device is connected to the internet with WiFi, you have to make sure ports 5228,5229,5230 are not blocked (usually 5228 is enough). As for the code, I'm sure the tutorial code works. Yours doesn't. That's why I asked for your code.

Comment: @Eran i already open port 5228,5229,5230 but still doesnt work

Comment: Was opening the ports what solved your problem, or did you fix something in your code?

Comment: after open certain port number that u said, i'll try to restart my laptop. Re-run the code again the apps npw is working finely..Thanks @Eran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems that my comment helped solve the problem, I'm posting it as an answer :

If your device is connected to the internet with WiFi, you have to make sure ports 5228,5229,5230 are not blocked (usually 5228 is enough).